# Gerar cabeçalho ao exportar dados para o excel

Tags: c#, oracle, microsoft-excel

Fiz uma rotina de exportação para o `excel`, usando `StreamWriter`, mas ela me gera uma problema. Não consigo pegar o nome das colunas que vêm no select. Para eu fazer o cabeçalho, tive que colocar na mão. Isso não seria o problema, a questão é ao abrir o arquivo, ele dá uma mensagem que o arquivo não é compatível, mas depois ele abre normalmente. Alguém tem um caminho diferente desse? Abaixo o código que gera o excel, baseado em um select no `Oracle`.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string caminho = @"C:\\Teste_Xls\\ListaCliente.xlsx";
            string error = string.Empty;

            DataExport dataExport = new DataExport();

            var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DTOP"].ConnectionString;

            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connection);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(caminho))
            {
                using (var connectionOracle = new OracleConnection(connection))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        var cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("Data Inclusao" + "\t" + "Tipo de Tabela" + "\t" + "Tabela" + "\t" + "Codigo" + "\t" + "TUSS");
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                DateTime dtInclusao = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
                                string tipoTabela = reader[1].ToString();
                                string tabela = reader[2].ToString();
                                Int64 codigo = Convert.ToInt64(reader[3]);
                                string tuss = reader[4].ToString();

                                sw.WriteLine(dtInclusao + "\t" + tipoTabela + "\t" + tabela + "\t" + codigo + "\t" + tuss);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        error = ex.Message;
                    }

                }


            }
            //CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(listaDataExport, @"C:\\Teste_Xls\\ListaCliente.xlsx");
        }
```

Comment: cara, busque sobre a API própria do Excel a "Microsoft.Interop.Excel" talvez ajude.

Answer (score 2):

vou lhe mostrar dois modos diferentes.
Essa questão acontecia comigo e a resolvi com o modo 1. Após sua pergunta, fui em busca de um novo caminho e implementei o método 2 em minha aplicação.

1) O mais simples:
  Ao invés de salvar como .xlsx, salve como .csv, e consequentemente, faça a divisão dos campos com ";".
O arquivo vai abrir sem mostrar qualquer mensagem.

2) Mais completo:
Nesse caso, faremos uso da **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** e teremos a possibilidade de salvar os dados em célula por célula.

Adicione a referência [minha versão é essa da imagem, a sua pode ser diferente]:
[image: Add Reference...]

E implemente o código

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
excelApp.Visible = false;
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(oMissing);
//Criando uma planilha
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets.Add(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
//Definindo o formato de saída [opcional]
excelApp.DefaultSaveFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12;
//Nomeando a planilha
excelSheet.Name = "Pesquisa";
```

O código acima vai criar um arquivo do tipo [que você definir] e o treço abaixo, será o lançamento dos dados na planilha 1.

```
//Salva na primeira linha, o cabeçalho da planilha
string[] cabecalho = {"Data Inclusao", "Tipo de Tabela", "Tabela", "Codigo,TUSS"};
for (int i = 0; i < cabecalho.Length; i++)
{
excelSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = cabecalho[i];
}
//Salva o conteúdo da tabela nas células
int linha = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    linha++;                          
    //Cells[linha, coluna]
    excelSheet.Cells[linha, 1] = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
    excelSheet.Cells[linha, 2] = reader[1].ToString();
    excelSheet.Cells[linha, 3] = reader[2].ToString();
    excelSheet.Cells[linha, 4] = Convert.ToInt64(reader[3]);
    excelSheet.Cells[linha, 5] = reader[4].ToString();                           
}
//Finalize salvando e fechando o excel da memória.
excelSheet.SaveAs(caminho);
excelApp.Quit();
```

Note que não vamos mais precisar do `StreamWriter`.